# Why doesn't this program detect that there is a whitespace?

Tags: c++, whitespace

So I was working on this program again, and I encountered another problem. I am testing if a character is a space. However, instead of detecting that the there is a space, it stops the loop and doesn't do anything more. Here is my code:

```
string reet(char reet) {
if (isspace(reet) == true) {
    return "IA";
}
else {
    switch (reet) {
    case 'a':
        return "Zg";
        break;
    case'b':
        return "dA";
        break;
    case 'c':
        return "dG";
        break;
    case 'd':
        return "aw";
        break;
    case 'e':
        return "bw";
        break;
    case 'f':
        return "dQ";
        break;
    case 'g':
        return "cg";
        break;
    case 'h':
        return "ZA";
        break;
    case 'i':
        return "cQ";
        break;
    case 'j':
        return "YQ";
        break;
    case 'k':
        return "eA";
        break;
    case 'l':
        return "dw";
        break;
    case 'm':
        return "cw";
        break;
    case 'n':
        return "ag";
        break;
    case 'o':
        return "eQ";
        break;
    case 'p':
        return "bA";
        break;
    case 'q':
        return "aA";
        break;
    case 'r':
        return "ZQ";
        break;
    case 's':
        return "cA";
        break;
    case 't':
        return "Yw";
        break;
    case 'u':
        return "eg";
        break;
    case 'v':
        return "bg";
        break;
    case 'w':
        return "aq";
        break;
    case 'x':
        return "bQ";
        break;
    case 'y':
        return "Yg";
        break;
    case 'z':
        return "Zw";
        break;
    default:
        return " ";
        break;
    }
}
}

string enc(string input) {
string sketchyBois = input;
string bigBoi = "";
int yeetL = sketchyBois.length() + 1;
for (int x = 0; x < yeetL;) {
    bigBoi = bigBoi + reet(sketchyBois[x]);
    x++;
}
return bigBoi;
}
```

I was just wondering if anyone can tell me why it is doing this? Thank you!

Comment: Where is the definition of `isspace`?

Comment: Why do you add 1 to `sketchyBois.length()`?

Comment: One problem is that your loop over `sketchyBois` goes out of bounds of the string.

Comment: Please read about [mcve]. If all the `24` letters are not necessary to reproduce the problem you should remove it from the code

Comment: On an unrelated note, why don't have `++x` in the `for` loop statement itself? Like `for (int x = 0; x < sketchyBois.length(); ++x)`?

Comment: `if (isspace(reet) == true)` -> `if (isspace(reet))` (`isspace` only returns a non-zero `int` value, not specifically `true`)

Comment: @user463035818 Without an MCVE we don't know if that's it.

Comment: @user463035818 Sorry should have been more clear, my comment was about the `isspace` link.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ah ok, completely agree, my mistake to jump in trying to answer what I was in fact not able to know

Comment: You don't really need to `break` after a `return`.

Comment: The place to start when a function isn't behaving the way you expect it to is with the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace). Even better: read the documentation before you write code.

Answer (score 7):

You need to change

```
if (isspace(reet) == true)
```

to

```
if (isspace(reet))
```

or

```
if (isspace(reet) != 0)
```

since [`isspace` only returns a non-zero `int` value for a white space character](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isspace), not a `bool`.

(Note that as a matter of coding style, it's generally preferred to omit comparison with `true` or `false` in boolean tests and just use `if (expr)` or `if (!expr)`.)

Comment: Another fun trick: `if (!!isspace(reet) == true)` will also work as `!!` forces the conversion from a numerical value to a boolean value. (Don't actually do this though)

Comment: @NathanOliver: yes - a great way to befuddle your colleagues who have never seen the "bang bang operator" before too! ;-)

Comment: In applications where it matters, evaluating against zero is generally more efficient.

Comment: It's more than just a matter of coding style; it is flat-out wrong to directly compare to `true` or `false`. It shows a fundamental misunderstanding of how an `if` statement evaluates an expression.

Comment: Paul R that didn't work. It still stops running after the space. For example the input I am a big boi returns just cQ.

Comment: @NipIsTrue With that change,`enc("I am a big boi")` produces `IAZgcwIAZgIAdAcQcgIAdAeQcQ ` (with a leading space). ([Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a4f4ec192217be8).) The problem lies in how you're reading the input before passing it to `enc`.

Comment: Ok. How do you think i can fix that.

Comment: Since you're now looking at a second problem outside the code you've shown us you should post a new question with a [mcve] that reproduces this new problem.

Comment: @molbdnilo I am passing the input as a string, inputed by the user.

Comment: @NipIsTrue I suspect that you're reading with `>>`, which reads word by word, separated by whitespace.

Comment: @molbdnilo is there an alternate way to do it?

Comment: @NipIsTrue You should use `getline`. And perhaps get one of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).